# How to align and compare two elements (sequence) in a list using python

Tags: python, list, compare, sequence, bioinformatics

here is my question:

I've got a file which looks like this:

> 103L   Sequence:   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL   Disorder:   ----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX

It contains name, which in this case is 103L; protein sequence, which has "Sequence:" label; disorder region, which is after "Disorder:". the "-" represent that this position is ordered, and "X" represent that this particular position is disordered. For example, that last two "XX" under disorder represent that the last two position of the protein sequence is disordered, which is "NL".
After I use split method, it looks like this:

['>103L', 'Sequence:', 'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL', 'Disorder:', '----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX']

I want to use python to find the disorder sequence and its position. So the final file should look somewhat like this:
Name Sequence: 'real sequence' 
Disorder: position(Posi) residue-name(R)
Take 103L as an example:

> 103L Sequence: MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>   Disorder: Posi R
>             34   K
>             35   S
>             36   p
>             37   S
>             38   L
>             39   N
>             65   N
>             66   L

I am new in python, really hope someone can help me, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break this up into three distinct parts:

1. parse the input;
2. construct the new disorder string;
3. output the new file.

(1) and (3) are pretty simple, so I'll focus on (2). The main thing you need to do is iterate through your "disorder string" where you can access the character at each position, as well as the position itself. One way to do this is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, x in enumerate(S)
```

which gives you a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for each position (stored in `i`) and character (stored in `x`) in string `S`. Once you have that, all you need to do is record the position and the character in `seq` whenever the disorder string has an `"X"`. In Python, this could look like:

```
if (x == 'X'):
    new_disorder.append( "{} {}".format(i, seq[i]) )
```

where we are formatting the result as a string, e.g. "34 R".

Here's a complete example:

```
# Parse the file which was already split into split_list
split_list = ['>103L', 'Sequence:', 'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL', 'Disorder:', '----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX']
header   = split_list[0] + " " + split_list[1]
seq      = split_list[2]
disorder = split_list[4]

# Create the new disorder string
new_disorder = ["Disorder: Posi R"]
for i, x in enumerate(disorder):
    if x == "X":
        # Appends of the form: "AminoAcid Position"
        new_disorder.append( "{} {}".format(i, seq[i]) )

new_disorder = " ".join(new_disorder)

# Output the modified file
open("seq2.txt", "w").write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
```

Note that I get slightly different output than the example you gave:

```
103L Sequence:
MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
Disorder: Posi R 34 K 35 S 36 P 37 S 38 L 39 N 165 N 166 L
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. But may I ask one more question? I run your example in python. and it gives me this: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"/Users/Jasonlin/PycharmProjects/Parsing_PDB/PDB/MDML_example.py", line 5, in <module>
    seq = lines[1].rstrip()
IndexError: list index out of range. \n So I assume that the seq. txt file that you use are a text file generated by the example I gave you right? Sorry to bother you again. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3817527: is your input all stored on one line? I was assuming that you had input across multiple lines, separated by the newline character `'\n'`.

Comment: I just copied the example into the txt file @mdml

Comment: @user3817527: I'm not sure I understand how your input is working, but if you can get the input into a `list` named `split_list` as in your example my code should work.

Comment: I still got a different error. it says:   File "/Users/Jasonlin/PycharmProjects/Parsing_PDB/PDB/MDML_example.py", line 20, in <module>
    open("/Users/Jasonlin/Documents/PDB/seq2.txt", "w").write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found.

Comment: And this is my code (I basically copied yours but I do parse the line into a list named split_list)                                  # Parse the file which was already split into split_list
lines = open("seq.txt")
for list in lines:
    split_list = list.split()
header = split_list[0:2]
seq = split_list[2]
disorder = split_list[4]

Comment: # Create the new disorder string
new_disorder = ["Disorder: Posi R"]
for i, x in enumerate(disorder):
    if x == "X":
        # Appends of the form: "AminoAcid Position"
        new_disorder.append("{} {}".format(i, seq[i]))

new_disorder = " ".join(new_disorder)

# Output the modified file
open("seq2.txt", "w").write( "\n".join([header, seq, new_disorder]))

Comment: @user3817527: you need to join the lists here: `header = "".join(split_list[0:2])`

Comment: @user3817527: glad to be of help!

Comment: Actually I have another question. What if I have multiple lists just like the example I showed you? I used your code on the file which contains multiple protein sequence and their corresponding disordered regions. They are all formatted correctly. There is no error but only the last sequence and its disordered region showed up. What should I do?

Comment: @user3817527: sounds feasible, maybe you can post it as a different question? I'd be happy to look at it. Also, if my answer solved your original problem, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green check box.

Answer (score 2):

suppose we have the results of the split command in a variable

```
split_list = ['>103L', 'Sequence:', 'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL', 'Disorder:', '----------------------------------XXXXXX-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XX']
```

lets work with just the important pieces, items 2 and 4,

```
res_name = split_list[2]  # ( i.e. 'MNIFEML...' )
disorder = split_list[4]  # ( i.e. '-----...XXX')
```

You can associate the elements of the two arrays like so.

```
sets = []
for i,c in enumerate( disorder ):
  if c == 'X':
    sets.append( (i, res_name[i]) )
```

The enumerate command in Python iterates through a list like object and returns an index and an item (i,c) for each member of disorder.  At the end of this operation, sets will contain tuples of what we're after, the index numbers where 'X' occurs in disorder and the corresponding residues from res_name.

```
sets = [(34,'K'), (35,'S') ... ]
```

If you want to use another nice Python feature you can construct sets in one line using whats called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ,

```
sets = [ (i,res_name[i]) for i,c in enumerate(disorder) if c=='X' ]
```

This is a quick way to build a list and will be more efficient than the loop although the difference shouldn't matter for on the order of 100 items as you've shown in your example.  The only thing left is to write this new data to file.  We can create a string in the format that you want by making another list and joining the pieces with a space between them.  For each tuple in list we want the string version of the index and the residue name (which is already a string).  This can be done list so,

```
txt = ' '.join( [str(t[0]) + ' ' + t[1] for t in sets] )
```

the variable txt will now be equal to

```
>>> txt 
'34 K 35 S 36 P 37 S 38 L 39 N 165 N 166 L'
```

To write out to a file with the format you specified you can do the following,

```
f = open( 'test.out', 'w' )
f.write( ' '.join(split_list[0:2]) + '\n' )
f.write( split_list[2] + ' Disorder: Posi R ' + txt )  
f.close()
```

the first write command puts '>103L Sequence:' on the first line and adds a new line character.  The second outputs the original residue sequence and the txt variable we created above.